# Is it possible to access parent component ngOnInit method from child component?

Tags: angular

i'm trying to access one component ngOnint method from another component.But i'm getting "Cannot read property 'ngOnInit' of undefined" error. How can i fix it?

Comment: its better if u can add your tried code and the error that u got,it help to provide best answers from users

Comment: Try to update your question with the code snippet instead of provding them in the comments

Comment: onSubmit(counsellingStudentForm, value) {
    let api = config.serverApiUrl.concat('studentCounsellings/' + this.requestedService.id).concat('/process-counsil');
    this.httpClient.put(api, value, {observe: 'response'})
      .subscribe(data => {
      if (data.status === 200) {
        Swal({
          text: 'Student counselled successfully.',
        });
        this.commonResource.modalRef.hide();
        this.counselingList.ngOnInit();
      } else {
        console.log(`Backend returned code ${data.status}, body was: ${data}`);
      }
    }
  }

Comment: Now am getting following error. 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'ngOnInit' of undefined
    at SafeSubscriber.eval [as _next] (process-counseling.component.ts:48)

Answer (score 0):

You need to know how to pass the data from one component to another,
For example pass the data from parent to child you must use decorator @Input here a well-explained example https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding,
and if you want to pass data from a child to a parent you must use decorator @Output here an example
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event